# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerViewController to play video from the server.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPlayer;
```

When i restart the video i get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (code=1, address=0xc000000c)...

```
_videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString ... ]]];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:_videoPlayer];
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: What's wrong with question and why thumbdown? I just learn make ios app about 2 weeks...

Comment: Arc is deallocating your movie player instance prematurely. Use the property setter to keep it around ie self.videoPlayer = ...aloc...init

Comment: So i write in the line videoPlayer = [[... alloc] initWIthContentURL:...];
Isn't the same thing u wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of searching answer, got solution!!!

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{    
// just add observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

and i need to stop player then user press Done:

```
- (IBAction) movieEventFullscreenHandler:(NSNotification*)notification{
[self.player.moviePlayer stop];
[self.player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
}
```

Thats all!

Answer (score 0):

i did use it to as present ..

but you can--

1. import mediaPlayer framework
   in your .h

   MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;
   NSString *strVideoURL;

in your .m

in your ViewDidLoad -

```
    NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:strVideoURL];
    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlVideo];
    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 270)]
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
```

or wherever  you want to play, pause, stop or restart